# What is wrong with the derivation?

Tags: integration, statistics, characteristic-functions

I want to evaluate

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{jtx}}{(1+x)^2}\,dx$$

where $j=\sqrt{-1}$ and $t$ is a real number. I did this change of variables $y=1/(1+x)$, which resulted in the integration

$$-\int_0^1e^{jt/y}\,dy=\frac{1}{jt}$$

As you can see, the original integral is actually the characteristic function of a random variable with a PDF $f_X(x)=(1+x)^{-2}$, and one of the properties of the characteristic function is that its value at $0$ is $1$, which isn't the case in my result, and the characteristic function always exists.

What's wrong with the derivation?

EDIT 1: I evaluated $dy=\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$, while it should be $dy=\frac{-dx}{(1+x)^2}$. So, the integral becomes

$$\int_0^1e^{jt/y}\,dy=\frac{-1}{jt}$$

EDIT 2: I forgot to the scaling factor $e^{jt}$, but the final result is still true. So, the integral is

$$e^{jt}\int_0^1e^{jt/y}\,dy=\frac{-1}{jt}$$

EDIT 3: The indefinte integral is evaluated as

$$e^{jt}\int e^{jt/y}\,dy = \frac{-e^{jt}}{jt}\,y^2e^{jt/y}$$

Comment: If $y= \frac 1{(1+x)}, $ then $x = \frac 1y -1$, and $dx = -\frac 1{y^2} dy $

Comment: $dy = -\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$, so, the $\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$ part in the integral can be substituted by $-dy$. I think I just forgot the minus sign, but otherwise, we agree. The problem still presents though.

Comment: $x \neq \frac 1y$.  Rather, $x = \frac 1y - 1$, given your substitution $y= \frac 1{1+x}$.

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot a term outside the integral. The final result is correct though. I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You evaluate the integral
as if the function was
$e^{jty}$.

Comment: Not exactly.  the OP thinks they are integrating $e^{jt/y}$

Comment: How I evaluated the integral as it was $e^{jty}$? Could you explain?